# Describe regular expression

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, regular-expressions

I am learning about regular expression, and  trying to describe a regular expression for the language L

> $\qquad L = \{a^i b^j c^k \mid i+j = k\}$

What is the right approach and how to describe a regular expression like this?

Comment: What do you mean by "describe"? Natural language or something else?

Comment: But L needs to be regular if you want to describe it via a regular expression.

Comment: To reiterate the other responses, there is NO POSSIBLE regular expression to describe language $L$, since it's not a regular language. Welcome to the site, by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems I didn't understand the question.

There is no regular expression for this language because it is not regular. You can prove it using the pumping lemma.

Comment: @0xAlon I edited the answer.